# Prevent Chrome/Chromium from wiping userscript settings when you clear cookies

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, privacy, chromium, userscripts

When you clear cookies/localstorage in Chrom* your userscript settings get wiped. Is there a way to preserve this in some way? I'd like to not have to reconfigure them every time I delete my browsing data.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the global storage for your data instead of cookies. This will cause the settings to be saved to the [config.xml](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Config.xml) file. If you do this you should make sure you aren't making this grow too huge though because it is parsed every browser load (not just when you visit a particular domain).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447950/script-to-save-settings) for more information on doing that.